# PyQt USB RFID Reader

Tags: python, pyqt, rfid

I have a simple USB RFID Reader
(https://www.elatec-rfid.com/fileadmin/Documents/Data-Sheet/DS-TWN4-MultiTech-2-LF-HF-DocRev8.pdf)

This Reader sends the RFID number through a "virtual" keyboard.
Is there a way to check if this keypressevent is coming from the "real" keyboard, or from the readers  "virtual" keyboard?

Or is there any other idea how i can access the readers data?
I can't acess the reader through serial because it does not create a serial port on connecting

PS: I am using Windows

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.key())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = MainWindow()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: See [QCoreApplication.installNativeEventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#installNativeEventFilter) and [this pyqt mailing list thread](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2015-April/035852.html).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install an eventFilter and an Êvent gets triggered when I use the scanner
but I have no idea what i should do with this

```
[('hWnd', <class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>), ('message', <class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>), ('wParam', <class 'ctypes.c_ulonglong'>), ('lParam', <class 'ctypes.c_longlong'>), ('time', <class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>), ('pt', <class 'ctypes.wintypes.POINT'>)]
```

The code now looks like this

```
import sys
import ctypes.wintypes
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractNativeEventFilter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget)

class RFID(QAbstractNativeEventFilter):
    def __init__(self):
        QAbstractNativeEventFilter.__init__(self)

    def nativeEventFilter(self, eventType, message):
        if eventType != "windows_generic_MSG":
            return

        msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG.from_address(message.__int__())
        print(msg._fields_)

        return False, 0

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    #def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    #    print(event.key())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # install event filter
    test = RFID()
    app.installNativeEventFilter(test)

    demo = MainWindow()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```